# How to sync two looping videos with mplayer and upd?

Tags: linux, video, sync, udp, mplayer

I am trying to sync two instances of mplayer with -upd-master and -udp-slave, and notice that the slave staggers for about a second when the master begins the loop anew.

I am running debian 7.1 with MPlayer SVN-r36545 and here are my commands for the two videos running on the same i7 8GBram 240GB SSD machine (acting as a dhcp server):

```
mplayer -vo xv -udp-master -udp-ip 10.42.0.255 -loop 0 Videos/HDV_0537.MP4
mplayer -vo xv -udp-slave -loop 0 Videos/HDV_0538.MP4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was actually really tricky, because the problem was that the `-loop 0` I had been using on the slave was actually waiting for the master to broadcast its position and sync up. In fact I talked to one of my friends who was one of the mplayer developers and he told me what I wanted to do was impossible.

So the hack that I ended up using was to constantly check the current position of the slave and just as it gets to the EOF restarting the file after a specific bit of sleep - which I had to tune by hand...

First to set up the master use this:

```
mplayer -udp-master -udp-ip 10.42.0.255 masterVideo.mp4 -loop 0
```

For the slave I used the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

fifo="/tmp/fifo"

rm -rf $fifo
mkfifo $fifo

mplayer -nocache -slave -fixed-vo -idle -udp-ip 10.42.0.255 -udp-slave -udp-seek-threshold 0.5 -osdlevel 0 -input file=$fifo >$fifo.answer "slaveVideo.mp4" &

somepid=$!
echo $somepid

function getpos() {
    local newpos=none
    while ! [[ "$newpos" =~ ANS_TIME ]]; do
        echo "get_time_pos" > $fifo
        newpos=$(tail -n 1 $fifo.answer)
        [[ "$newpos" =~ "EOF code: 1" ]] && { pos=-1; echo > $fifo.answer; return; } 
        pos=${newpos#ANS_TIME_POSITION=}
    done
    pos=${pos#0}
    pos2=$(echo "$pos + 0.14" | bc )
    printf "%.2f" "$pos2"
} 

function getlen() {
    local newlen=none
    while ! [[ "$newlen" =~ ANS_LENGTH ]]; do
        echo "get_time_length" > $fifo
        newlen=$(tail -n 1 $fifo.answer)
        len=${newlen#ANS_LENGTH=}
        sleep 0.1
    done
    len=${len#0}
    echo ${len}
}

len=$(getlen)

while true; do
    pos=$(getpos)
    if [[ $pos == $len ]]
        then
            # YOU MUST TWEAK THE FOLLOWING
            # SLEEP TIME FOR YOUR MACHINE
            sleep 0.5
            echo "loadfile /media/media/1.mp4" > $fifo
        fi
done
```

By the way, I am using a compiled mplayer - not mplayer2. Pause works very cleanly, as does skip... However, it is quite important that the two files have exactly the same duration and use the same codecs...

Answer (score 1):

First let me thank you man.  I have been using mplayer in multi monitors for nearly 15 years now.  I was simply never able to get it working and I found nothing on the internet that worked.  It felt so ridiculous like why has no one ever thought of this?

Man your script worked and I couldnt believe it, after all this time!  Thanks so much man!  I scripted it into files masterVideo and slavedVideo, I added the command line args to the file so i can call masterVideo and slavedVideo with the movie name as well.  I also added -volume 0 to the slave script cause the sound was echoing.  Its rough and hacky but its working!

On the same computer is working fine...  I am now trying to use this script across the network, but it only works on the same computer for now.  Is there a way to launch a slavedVideo across the network using the ip address?  When I try it only works if the master and slave are on the same machine.  Here is the exact error

---

```
armel@shiva:~/tmp$ ../bin/slavedVideo movie.avi
76666
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote 
control.
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f63c469c380]Requested frame threading with a custom         
get_buffer2() implementation which is not marked as thread safe. This is 
not supported anymore, make your callback thread-safe.
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: _
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
^C

MPlayer interrupted by signal 2 in module: sleep_timer
```

---

I searched it and ended up putting lirc=no in my .mplayer/config file, then the movie would start paused but never sync and I would get this error.  The movies are exactly the same file.

---

```
armel@shiva:~/tmp$ ~/bin/slavedVideo movie.avi 
936655
[mpeg4 @ 0x7fdb253d7380]Requested frame threading with a custom     
get_buffer2() implementation which is not marked as thread safe. This is 
not supported anymore, make your callback thread-safe.
^C
MPlayer interrupted by signal 2 in module: calc_sleep_time
```

---

So I added on to the solution, but networking is not working...  Is there some additional setup required to get this working across the network?  Both machines are connected fine with ssh.  I realize this post was a long time ago, thought I would reach out and try anyway.  What you have already done has been extremely helpful man thanks.  :)